# Laravel faker array in order

Tags: mysql, laravel, faker

So I've got a laravel factory called categories. I've got an array of categories that I want to be added to my database. I can use randomElement to add them but I don't want them in random order.

```
    $randomCategory = $faker->randomElement($array = array ('category1', 'category2', 'category3'));
```

I want them to be added to my database in that order. So id 1 = category 1, id 2 = category 2 etc.
How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure what you're after. Why use `$faker` _and_ `randomElement()` if you already have names and a predefined order for your categories? Why do this in a factory, shouldn't that be done in a seeder?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a seeder which will fill your database with the categories you want. You don't need to use faker for this.

Answer (score 0):

Current Laravel versions let you define [sequences](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#sequences) for a given model attribute (at least version 10.x does). Thus, you can alternate between given values, or use the values in a sequence, e.g.:

```php
$randomCategory = YourModel::factory()->count(3)->sequence(
    ['category' => 'category1'], 
    ['category' => 'category2'], 
    ['category' => 'category3']
)->create();
```